# Rejected payments from Google Play

Tags: android, credit-card, google-play

I have a small android app that is available for purchase on Google Play. I have noticed that recently about 60% of all downloads result in a Credit Card rejected by Google Play.

Why is this such a large percentage? I would expect that a few cards would be rejected because people forget to update them, but 60% is very high. Is there some sort of scam going on to get software for free? Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is a good question, but I'm not sure if it is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for this site because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: Agreed this question should be closed as irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about that, Google takes care of credit card processing. Usually this happens when the same person tries to buy your software again and again and makes a mistake in his CC number or other information. Eventually (s)he will figure out the mistake and the payment gets through. Or not.